# Multiple fields in where not working correctly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have this

```
    viaurldb = Via.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND viadate = ? ', ["%#{tmname}%", "%#{tmdate}%"]).first
```

So i have this at the moment.

However i'm getting this at the moment.

```
ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: product_name ILIKE ? AND viadate = ?
```

Any ideas?

Tahnks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the square brackets, you are sending one array, instead of two arguments:

```
viaurldb = Via.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND viadate = ? ', "%#{tmname}%", "%#{tmdate}%").first
```

Comment: Are you asking another question? You might want to post it separately. If my answer solves your original question, please mark it as a solution and post a different question regarding why split is not working?